# Android activity recognition with errors

Tags: java, android

I am using avtivity recognition for android to detect user activities. Some of the time i get data with errors 
For example it show user activity as in vehicle even if i am still. 
How can i remove these errors?

Comment: How do you expect any help if we cant see any code or errors?